# writing result of apply-templates in seperate element

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I am new to xml, xslt and I have two xml files. I want to compare both files and display the record which is present in first file and not in second file.

first xml:

```
<employees>
 <employee> 
  <id>1</id>
  <name>aaa</name>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>2</id>
  <name>bbb</name>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>3</id>
  <name>ccc</name>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>4</id>
  <name>ddd</name>
 </employee>
</employees>
```

second xml:

```
<developers>
 <developer>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>aaa</name>
 </developer>
 <developer>
  <id>3</id>
  <name>ccc</name>
 </developer>
</developers>
```

my XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="updates"   select="document('file:///D:/vishal/Talend_vishal/Examples/14-10- 2015/HMergeAssignment/XML_mog_identiteit.xml')" />

 <xsl:variable name="updateItems" select="$updates/developers/developer" />

 <xsl:template match="/employees/employee">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="id"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/employees">
  <refid><xsl:apply-templates select="employee[not(id = $updateItems/id)]"/>
 </refid>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my output:

```
<refid>24</refid>
```

required output:

```
<refid>2</refid>
<refid>4</refid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the creation of the `refid` element in the wrong place. You have put it in the template that matches `employees`, of which there is only one such element in the XML. You should really put it in the template that matches `employee`

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:param name="updates"   select="document('file:///D:/vishal/Talend_vishal/Examples/14-10- 2015/HMergeAssignment/XML_mog_identiteit.xml')" />

 <xsl:variable name="updateItems" select="$updates/developers/developer" />

 <xsl:template match="/employees/employee">
   <refid>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="id"/>
   </refid>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/employees">
  <refids>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee[not(id = $updateItems/id)]"/>
  </refids>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, I am creating a `refids` element in the `employees` template, just so that the XSLT outputs well-formed XML.